# How do I use a part of a file name in python as a unique identifier on which to base a join?

Tags: python, operating-system

Disclaimer: I'm absolutely a beginner to python outside of arcpy.

I'm trying to save some time uploading many file attachments to some GIS data layers. I've got a folder of files that I need to index and then join to another table using that index. The unique identifier that matches the column I want to base the join on is the seven characters at the start of the file name. I'm using python, and it seems like os is the way to do this. I haven't been able to find a good example about how to break out identifiers within file name as a variable.

For example:
If my files are 11-2232easement.pdf, 43-5223deed.pdf, 44-2321grant.pdf, how would I loop through this kind of file list and create a variable that is essentially is the first seven characters of each file?

Comment: You should show the code where you are running into problems so we are all staring at the same information. However, you might need to just check this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import join, isfile

my_dir = r'C:\Temp\my_files'  # Just for the purpose of this example
files = [f for f in listdir(my_dir) if isfile(join(my_dir, f))]

for file in files:
    identifier = file[0:7]
```

Comment: While this is answering the literal question, it looks like the question would be better served by doing some simple pattern matching, instead of just pulling out the first seven characters always.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes, that would be great to have the option to apply this to something other than the first seven characters. I just looked into pattern matching and found pypatt: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypatt-- is that what you're referring to?